# Tricky query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 table with Users and another one with Groups.
This both tables are connected by ID.

At the table Groups I got many lines for a single user, like:

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Jhonn | Admin |
| Jhonn | Common |
| Jhonn | RH |

I'm trying to know all users from the table Users that are not in the Admin group at the Group table.

I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT ID FROM USER u
JOIN GROUPS g
ON u.ID = g.ID
WHERE g.GROUP NOT IN ('Admin')
```

But this query is giving me

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Jhonn | Common |
| Jhonn | RH |

How can I make a query to know if the user is not with the Admin group?

Comment: Don't tag extra things that are not being used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, based on your requirements that Jhonn shouldn't appear:

```
SELECT ID FROM USER u
JOIN GROUPS g
ON u.ID = g.ID
WHERE u.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM GROUPS WHERE GROUP = 'Admin')
```

And depending on what columns you need from the tables, you could drop the join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM USERS U
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM GROUPS G WHERE U.ID=G.ID AND G.GROUP='Admin'
 )
```

Could you please try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and test for non-existence of a group:

```sql
SELECT u.ID
FROM   USER u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GROUPS g
       ON (u.ID = g.ID AND g.group = 'Admin')
WHERE  g.id IS NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d02fdd19c045898d978de989dc899ec8)*